# How can I turn the result of this javascript into a php variable?

Tags: php, location

There is a nifty piece of code that lets users start typing a place name, then offers suggested locations as you type.

Clicking on the desired location then places the location name into a div box. How can i get that selected value as a variable $location?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<style>
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
}
#city { width: 25em; }
</style>

<script>
$(function () {
    function log(message) {
        $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
        $("#log").scrollTop(0);
    }
    $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.geonames, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                            value: item.name
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            log(ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Divs:**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="city">Your city: </label>
<input id="city" />
<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top: 2em; font-family: Arial;">
Result:
<div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indent! Indent! Indent!

Comment: `How can i get that selected value as a variable $location?` Using Ajax, pretty much like you're already using in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this nifty piece of code for filling a form, what user can submit and php can work with on serverside, then you have to make it a form and give city field an appropriate name:

```
<form method="post">

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="city">Your city: </label>
<input id="city" name="city" />
<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top: 2em; font-family: Arial;">
Result:
<div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="ok" />

</form>

<?php
if (!empty($_POST['city'])){
    print('<div>Latest submitted city was: '.$_POST['city'].'</div>');
}
?>
```

Put this amended stuff (together with javascript) into a .php file and point your browser to this.

**EDIT:**

Alternative way would be to use cookie :)

Before success() return in your code set a cookie:

```
success: function (data) {
    response($.map(data.geonames, function (item) {
        document.cookie = 'location=' + encodeURIComponent(item.name) + '; path=/';
        return {
            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
            value: item.name
        }
    }));
}
```

In your PHP you can read this as:

```
$location = $_COOKIE['location'];
print($location);
```

Comment: Ooh, I will try this after I finish my din dins and get back to you